# How to copy time stamp to iOS clipboard?

Tags: ios

Does anyone know of an easy way to get the current timestamp copied to the clipboard on iOS, either via built-in functionality or a small app?

Comment: You would have to get that from a 3rd-party app because there isn't a shortcut in iOS to get that info.  Are you open to using an app to generate the timestamp?

Comment: yes definitely open to using an app, I'm looking for one to be recommended because I haven't found one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an app that does exactly this.  Time Stamp Text by CA Smith
https://appsto.re/us/fPUO1.i

I don't have any connection with the developer, but needed the same thing and found it.

Comment: Confirmed on iPhone SE! Pure gold.

Comment: This app is not available in my country, the United States?! I have never understood region discrimination anyway.