# Use variables in OS X Text Replace

Tags: text-input, auto-complete

Prompted by this question - [How to copy time stamp to iOS clipboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255685/how-to-copy-time-stamp-to-ios-clipboard)

Is there any way to use variables in OS X's standard Text Replacement?
[System Prefs > Keyboard > Text]

For instance, getting it to replace $DATE with today's date, or $TIME with the current time, $DEITY with The Flying Spaghetti Monster etc etc

<sup>the last one is a joke, btw ;)</sup>

Comment: You'll need a third party application, such as [aText](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/)

Comment: ...if you don't [want to use a hotkey](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242547/how-to-automatically-paste-todays-date-with-keyboard-shortcut/242577#242577).